# Unmet dependencies while installing SDL libraries

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

i have been trying to install sdl libraries on my Ubuntu 18.04 and it's been hours and i could not fathom how to make it happen. I've made many google searches for similar problems but nothing's working.
after using apt-get, the following error messages are displayed:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (= 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.8) but it is not going to be installed
```

the above is while installing libsdl2-2.0

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

this one is while installing libsdl2-dev

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

and this third one while installing libsdl2-image-dev

also, while fixing broken install, the following error messages are displayed:

```
Unpacking mesa-common-dev:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-common-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/gl.h', which is also in package libgl-dev:amd64 1.3.2-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libegl1-mesa-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl1-mesa-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/EGL/egl.h', which is also in package libegl-dev:amd64 1.3.2-1
Preparing to unpack .../libgles2-mesa-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h', which is also in package libgles-dev:amd64 1.3.2-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mesa-common-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl1-mesa-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa-dev_20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb
```

edit: I have used aptitude with no success